# System.Web.dll different version giving me problems in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a VB.NET web application project written in VS2010 targeted to the .Net 2.0 framework (don't ask I know). I have a class with an import statement that says

```
Imports System.Web.HttpContext
```

Lower down I try to use

```
Current.Session("username") = "user"
Current.Session("psswd") = "psswd"
Current.Session("dbName") = "database"

If (IsNothing(Current.Session("username")) Or IsNothing(Current.Session("psswd")) Or IsNothing(Current.Session("dbName"))) Then
    Current.Response.StatusCode = 402
Else
      ' Do some stuff here
End if
```

It works fine on my personal machine (windows xp SP3) but breaks on the server. I can't debug it on the server so I'm relying on stack trace to give me the error.

Stacktrace gives me

```
[NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Container..ctor(Object Instance) +497860
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) +373
letter_main.Logon.login_user() in C:\VSProjects\letter_main\letter_main\Old_App_Code\Logon.vb:55
letter_main._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\VSProjects\letter_main\letter_main\Default.aspx.vb:32
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +62
```

Line 55 in Logon.vb is the line 'Current.Response.StatusCode = 402' which it should never get to if it managed to put the values in the session. I'm guessing it hasn't?

So I investigated System.Web.dll on both of the machines and I found both were registered in the c:\%WINDIR%\assemblies from the location C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll but I had a different version on the server than on my local machine

Version on server is: 2.0.50727.3053
Version on my machine is: 2.0.50727.3614

Could this be the cause of my problem? Can anyone think of a good way to troubleshoot? The server is windows 2003, not sure if I can just copy it's System.Web.dll and use regasm to test on my local machine? I can't replace the server version as there are other web apps running there that will need it.

Comment: Given the reference to `NewLateBinding`, I'd at least try `Option Strict On` to see if you've got glaring errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers of this, my problem turned out to be fairly strange. I couldn't get things from the Session object at all in my classes. It worked fine in the codebehind pages though. I started a new project and copied my code there manually and it started working ok. I believe it was because I had made a mistake in the conversion from a website to a webapp. Not sure what the root cause was...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your issue has anything to do with the DLL versions.  I think something is not working correctly with the way you are using your `Imports` statement.  It is common practice to import only namespaces, not classes.  Because the exception message mentions a `With` block (and when you import a class rather than a namespace you are performing an action similar to what a `with` block is doing), I believe that is the source of your problem.

Try this:  Change your Imports to simply `Imports System.Web`.  Then reference the session as `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

This will tell you if that is the problem.  Why it's working OK in your local machine and not on the server I don't have any suggestions.  But start by seeing if that is the source of the problem and then hone-in on it from there...

Comment: Thanks for responding, you're right about the Import statement, I've changed that but still getting the same error. I grabbed the dll from the server and used regasm and re imported to my project, still works fine in dev, still broken on the server, so it's not the dll either.

Comment: Can you confirm if I'm reading the stacktrace correctly - I think Old_App_Code\Logon.vb:55 means look at line 55 in Logon.vb correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The exception is being generated at line 55.